# Why the FlashVars have 1 empty element

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

```
            var images:Array = new Array();
            var flashVars:Object = stage.loaderInfo.parameters;

            for (var key:String in flashVars)
            {
                var value:String = flashVars[key] as String;
                images.push(value);
            }
            trace(images.length) // outputs 1
```

I am getting images urls from flashVars html, but i can't understand why there are an empty element, why this code outputs 1? if there are not flashVars passed to the application?

Comment: I've tested in the adobe flash cs5, not in browser

Comment: sorry for this question, my mistake is that i've created it like this new array(''), rather than new array(), question closed